# Format comma for a bit 64 integer

Tags: r, bit64

Is there anyway to make the formatC type function work on big integers (int64)? Tried to look everywhere.

This clearly won't work, but looking for an equivalent:

```
x <- 2254728285
formatC(x, big.mark = ',', format = 'd')
[1] "NA"
Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "integer" :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

This works, and what I want, but for integer64 numbers:

```
x <- 22547282
formatC(x, big.mark = ',', format = 'd')
[1] "22,547,282"
```

Comment: Note that `typeof(x)` in this case is "double". Base R doesn't expose a 64bit integer type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```r
formatC(x, big.mark = ',', format = "f", digits = 0)
#[1] "2,254,728,285"

formatC(x, big.mark = ',', format = "fg")
#[1] "2,254,728,285"
```

Comment: `format = "fg"` will have no trailing zeros for integer